# Is there an HTML entity for an info icon?

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities

I am looking for a basic information icon like this:

[image]

Comment: Bit late with an answer but you could use Font-Awesome, there is loads of icons with that. https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/  you would just tag your css with fa-info-circle

Answer (score 235, accepted):

After some more searching, I myself have found the entity. The code for it is `&#9432;`, and it looks like this: ⓘ

Comment: This character appears for me on OS X 10.11 running Chrome. While it does show up, you may run into some accessibility issues compared to @Biffen's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33878646/4556503

Comment: @hopkins-matt - I can see the character in this answer, but on Windows/Firefox, in 2017, I still can't see the character in Biffen's answer... (?)

Comment: `&#128712;` `&#8505;` and `&#9432;` html entities will give you info buttons.

Comment: Only &#8505; and &#9432; will show up correctly on iphone and ipad.  The former is light blue rounded square with a white "i" in the middle.

Comment: @JohnHenckel can you please tell how to use &#9432 code in swift for the string.

Comment: @KhushbooDhote sorry, no, i'm not using swift. I am using vscode and running my app in safari

Comment: @KhushbooDhote I don't use Swift, but you should be able to just copy and paste the ⓘ from above (or my comment) into any string literal in Xcode. That's what I do for Objective-C++, as Xcode supports Unicode (as do pretty much all modern code editors). That way the characters appear more or less the same way in source code as they'll appear in the running app, instead of as some cryptic digits in the source code.

Comment: On macOS you can simply pull up the **Emoji & Symbols** pane from the Edit menu. In the top-right corner of the window is a button to show larger view, and from here you can look up emoji and symbols and the unicode hex by right-clicking on a symbol and choosing **Copy Character Information**

Answer (score 50):

There's  (U+1F6C8, CIRCLED INFORMATION SOURCE). As an HTML entity: `&#x1F6C8;`.

---

<sup>There are plenty of tools, many online, that let you search for, and get more information about, Unicode characters. My personal favourite is [this one](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/).</sup>

Comment: This character does not appears for me on OS X 10.11 running Chrome, but I would say that this character is semantically more appropriate.

Comment: @hopkins-matt Hm, that's a shame. If one wants to use it one might want to specify a font that contains it. Which goes for most non-ASCII characters, if one wants to be safe.

Comment: I agree. I'm sure it's simply an issue of the font choice.

Comment: Still not displaying in Firefox 2020. Require extra fonts configuration.

Comment: Use in CSS: `p::before { content: "\1f6c8"; }` I needed that. Only testing in Chrome on Win10, BTW.

Comment: a really smooty icon, tks a lot!

Comment: This character renders as a box on Samsung devices, so if not wanting to confuse a large % of portable devices users, choose another character.

Answer (score 7):

this may help you ,
using html and css we can achieve this results

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">


<div class="tooltip">&#x1F6C8;
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

UNICODE   `U+02139`

HEX CODE  `&#x2139;`

HTML CODE   `&#8505;`

CSS CODE  `\2139`

```css
// css example
span {
  content: "\2139";
}
```

```html
HTML Example

<span>&#8505;</span>
```

[Source](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/information-source/)

Answer (score 6):

These days I use emoji for "info" ℹ️ or "documentation"  or "source"

Previously, I would put the ⓘ inside superscript <sup>ⓘ</sup> because it reflects that it is a footnote to the text.

`<sup>&#9432;</sup>`

Also, consider the ☰ symbol over the  as it respects the baseline.

Answer (score 5):

HTML Code: `&#8505;`

CSS Code: `\2139`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the unicode: `&#9432;` into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping an `i` inside a `div` with a border (you can tweak the details as needed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div.i {
        font-family: serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 1em;
        padding-left: 0.4em;
        padding-right: 0.4em;
        width: 0.5em;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="i">i</div>

</body>
</html>
```